# Trying to install Meteor on CentOS

Tags: centos, meteor

I have a brand new install of CentOS 6 64bit. I've been going through the [installation](http://meteorserver.org/installation/) process and when I get to #3 to start it up [it looks like it's started](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGhW6.jpg).

Trying to do #4, I open a new PuTTY window connect on port 4670 in Raw mode then type in `GET /push/1/iframe/test HTTP/1.1` and hit enter twice. Nothing happens on either screen and the raw on crashed after a few seconds.

I have port 80 and 4670 open in iptables. Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong/not doing?

Comment: Did you check your logs? Is meteord running?

Comment: When I start it through init.d it just show "Starting Meteord:" then takes me back to the prompt. It has a log that shows it started with the process. The processes show "root     11653  0.0  0.5 135896  5580 pts/0    S    23:23   0:00 meteord daemon". The PID matches the log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work. What I did was disabled SELinux, rebooted and made sure my ports were set correctly in the firewall. After I did that, it worked.